# Issue removing node from list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am having trouble removing nodes from a singly linked list. When attempting to remove none first node. It seems to loose reference for the rest of the list.
Can someone help?
This is the function in question, it takes the head of the list and the plate of the node to be removed.

```
Car * removeCarFromList(Car * list,char plate[]){
    Car * current = list;
    Car * previous = NULL;
    while (current != NULL){
        if (strcmp(current->plate,plate)==0&& previous == NULL){
            list = current -> next;
            current -> next = NULL;
            return current;
            break;
        } else if (strcmp(current->plate,plate)==0&& previous != NULL){
            previous -> next = current -> next;
            current -> next = NULL;
            return current;
            break;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current -> next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The first node in a list ***is*** the *list address*. When you change the first node, you must also change the address stored as the list address. Therefore you have two options: 1) pass the *address of* the first node in the list so it can be assigned the new first node address in the function, or 2) return the new list address from the function as assign that address as the new list address in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing the first element from the list, than any pointers you have to list are now invalid. when you set `list = current -> next;` that value of list is local to your function, it never goes back out of your function to update the pointer that you pass to the function for the start of your list.

To do what you want, you will need a pointer to a pointer.

`Car * removeCarFromList(Car ** list,char plate[])`
then change current to: `Car * current = *list;`
then change `list = current->next` to `*list = current->next;`

Then when calling your function change `removeCarFromlist(myPointer,....`to `removeCarFromlist(&myPointer, ....`

This will change myPointer to point to next item in list when first item is removed.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I am trying to bubble sort my list based in milage of cars, where the list goes from lowest to highest. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Once you `return` from a function, there is no *return back* to the next instruction to the same function, so use of `break` after `return` is nonsensical. First, get rid of `break` statement after `return`.

Function handling linked list node removal must *handle the deletion of `head` node **separately***, making sure that the new `head` is updated to next node.

```
Node *tmp = *head;
*head = tmp->next;
free(tmp);
```